# RecyclerView duplicando items al iniciar la aplicacion

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, activity

Al iniciar el fragment y cargar el recyclerview duplica los items.

```
 private void loadData() {
    if (categoriaList.size() > 0)
        categoriaList.clear();
    miprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    db.collection("categoria")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                            CategoriaModel cat = new CategoriaModel(doc.getString("nombre"), doc.getString("url"), doc.getId());
                            categoriaList.add(cat);
                        }
                        adapter = new CategoriaAdapter((MainActivity) getActivity(), categoriaList);
                        listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
                        miprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
}
```

En mi onresume y onactivity created lo tengo asi:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listItem = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_categorias);
    miprogress =  getView().findViewById(R.id.circularProgress);
    layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    listItem.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadData();

}
```

Lo curioso aquí es que cuando cambio de Activity o a otro fragment, la lista no se duplica y queda bien. No se porque solo pasa al iniciar la aplicación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que debes tener cuidado al poblar un `Adapter` en el ciclo de vida del Fragment `onResume()`. Este método sobreescrito suele ser muy peligroso a la hora de cargar tareas si no se valida de manera correcta. Estas cometiendo dos **errores** importantes.

**1.** Estas poblando la data en `onResume()`, lo cual puede ser `disparado` múltiples veces antes de que la data sea poblada o tenga chance de llegar. Recuerda que la data tarda un poco en llegar, así que al ser disparado múltiples veces puede que el resultado llegue la misma cantidad de veces que se disparo el evento antes de que agregue algún resultado. Como resultado se duplicara la data.

`onResume()` puede ser llamado múltiples veces si los Fragments no están implementado de manera correcta en el `Activity`. Al igual que Apagar y encender la pantalla rapidamente, etc...

**Posibles soluciones**:

- Declara una variable `boolean` que valide tu carga de datos. por ejemplo:

`private boolean isDataLoaded;`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!isDataLoaded){
       loadData();
    }
}
```

Luego al principio de tu metodo `loadData()` vuelve la variable `isDataLoaded = true` y en el `onFailure` del task vuelvela `false`, esto por si tienes un refresh que quiera llamar el método nuevamente.

- Otra opción seria mover `loadData()` al `onCreateView` del Fragment.

**2.** Estas cometiendo los siguientes errores en el metodo `loadData()`:

```
adapter = new CategoriaAdapter((MainActivity) getActivity(), categoriaList);
listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
```

- El código de creación del adapter debe ser definido antes de    modificar la lista (en el `onCreateView` u `onActivityCreated`).    Estas haciendo que por cada vez que la lista se modifique, recrear un    nuevo adaptador, lo cual genera mucha basura para el `GC`. Recuerda    que al definirlo tu lista `categoriaList` no debe ser `null` y el    codigo que debe ir en el task, es `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`    corriendo en el hilo principal.
- Estas limpiando la lista de manera erronea (al principio del metodo `loadData()`). Cuando realmente dicho if deberia ir dentro del `onComplete`. Se puede dar el escenario en que la lista se borre y el `onComplete` nunca devuelva resultado. Por lo cual tendrias la lista de tu adapter modificada pero nunca notificada y te podria causar problemas.

**Solucion:** mueve el if al onComplete, deberia quedarte algo asi:

```
private void loadData() {
    isDataLoaded = true;
    miprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    db.collection("categoria")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (categoriaList.size() > 0)
                        categoriaList.clear();

                   for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                        CategoriaModel cat = new CategoriaModel(doc.getString("nombre"), doc.getString("url"), doc.getId());
                        categoriaList.add(cat);
                   }
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   miprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
       })
       .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                   isDataLoaded = false;
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        });
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    listItem = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_categorias);
    miprogress =  getView().findViewById(R.id.circularProgress);
    layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    listItem.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new CategoriaAdapter((MainActivity) getActivity(), categoriaList);
    listItem.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!isDataLoaded)
       loadData();

}
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias